# HDFStore initialization error: name is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, hdfstore

When I initialize HDFStore

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd    
hdf = pd.HDFStore('polar.h5')
```

I see an error in flavor.py:

> NameError, name '_conv_python_to_python' is not defined

[image]

I am using anaconda and pandas does work for dataframe stuff

Comment: If I run the code without visual studio code then it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it by adding:

```
import h5py
from pandas import HDFStore,DataFrame
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not a real problem. I checked Breakpoint: "All Exceptions" and it paused here, simply unchecking it resolves the issue. You can continue from this error.